# socket.io unique color for admin/user

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm currently messing with socket.io & node.js, I was wondering how I would set the color of an admin for example to red but only setting it to the admin & not for other users.

this is how I'm trying to do it (color red for admins & normal color for non-admins):

```
    socket.on('connected users', function(data){
      console.log(data.rank);
        var html = '';
        for(i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
          if(data.rank == "Admin"){
            html += '<li class="list-group-item text-lightred">' + data.users[i] +'</li>';
          }else{
            html += '<li class="list-group-item">' + data.users[i] +'</li>';
        }
      }
      $users.html(html);
    });
```

but since everyone receives the "data.rank" parameter it will apply to everyone.

This is my serversided code (emit)

```
            io.sockets.emit('connected users', {
              users: users,
            });
```

I'm new to node.js & socket.io, so I'm kinda stuck on that.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit:// Adding connected users to array

```
            const userName = sanitizer.escape(chatusername);
            users.push(userName);
            users[socket.id] = {userName, userRank};
            console.log(users[socket.id]);
```

clientside:

```
        socket.on('connected users', function(data){
            var html = '';
            for(i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
        console.log(data.users[i].userRank);
        console.log(data);
        if(data.users[i].userRank == "Admin"){
          html += '<li class="list-group-item text-lightred">' + data.users[i] +'</li>';
        }else{
          html += '<li class="list-group-item">' + data.users[i] +'</li>';
        }
      }
      $users.html(html);
    });
```

Comment: change `if(data.rank == "Admin"){` to `if (data.users[i].rank == "Admin") {`, then put the rank on each user array item when connecting, it would help if you showed how you adding the user to users array

Comment: I added how I add the users to the array/map, also "data.users[i].rank" returns undefined

Comment: yeah it would, you would need to do `users.push({userName, userRank});`, then change all the client side code which is just expecting an array of strings and use `data.users[i].userName` and `data.users[i].userRank` instead.. basically, you need to assign the rank to each user item before putting it in the array, then when receiving the array clientside you know the rank.. as-is your code is just responding with own rank so the feature your after is not possible.

Comment: sidenote you could plop it all in `users`, like `users[socket.id] = {userName, userRank};`, then you can know from the client what socket id each user has, and its easyier to maintain the object with `delete users[socket.id]` on disconnect etc, also you have Object.values(users) if you ever need an array

Comment: Okay, I'm using the users array only now, I edited my post above with the new code & it's still giving me "undefined" on `data.users[i].userRank`, not sure if I'm doing something wrong - the `console.log(users[socket.id]);` gives me the output `{ userName: 'username', userRank: 'Admin' }` tho.

Comment: yeah you're still pushing a string to `users`, also its now an object so should change the for loop to iterate over an object, do a a `console.log(data)` and your see what it looks like then change the output code to suit, heres a little example which covers what you need: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-flower-6pqgp?file=/src/public/index.html (open in couple of tabs your see)

Comment: Hey, I got it working with your help, thank you really much! :)